# Why a Runtime Error reading File

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Hi I am asking a why question**

I am wondering why my code won't work how I want it to output, Logic and/or Runtime Errors?

What I need it to do is read a text file then output how many times the user input is typed in. I have a word already pre-inputed so no hassle with inputting everytime.

I just need clarification on how to read a text file with the scanner class.
**Thanks here is the code.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class P6B
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
    //vaiables
    Scanner reader = new Scanner ( new File("README.TXT"));
    Scanner txtString = new Scanner (reader.nextLine());
    //Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int CountWord = 0;
    String word;

    System.out.println( reader.next() + "\nThis program will read a text file with 50 random   words"
                        + "\nWhat word would you like to look up that may be repeated: ");
    word = "the";  //input.nextLine();
    while ( txtString.hasNext())
    {

        while (txtString.equals(word)){
            System.out.println( "TEST2" );
            CountWord++;
            reader.next();
        }
    }//to get words and return the value of how many times it was found
    if ( CountWord != 0)System.out.println( "\nI have found your word " + CountWord + " times.");
    else if ( CountWord == 0) 
        {
            System.out.println ( "\nNo word found in the text file." );
        }//end of if if error
 }//end of main method
 }//end of class assignment
```

Ok saw your comments I will put out the Runtime errors.  I checked again and now I don't get a run-time error anymore.

This is confusing the heck out of me.

Here is my output:

```
The
This program will read a text file with 50 random words
What word would you like to look up that may be repeated: 

No word found in the text file.
```

**WHY**
confusing me.

Here is the text file.

```
The woolly mammoth (Mammuthus primigenius) was a species of mammoth, the common name for the     extinct elephant genus Mammuthus. The woolly mammoth was one of the last in a line of mammoth  species, beginning with Mammuthus subplanifrons in the early Pliocene. M. primigenius diverged from  the steppe mammoth, M. trogontherii, about 200,000 years ago in eastern Asia. Its closest extant relative is the Asian elephant.
The appearance and behaviour of this species are among the best studied of any prehistoric animal because of the discovery of frozen carcasses in Siberia and Alaska, as well as skeletons, teeth, stomach contents, dung, and depiction from life in prehistoric cave paintings. Mammoth remains had long been known in Asia before they became known to Europeans in the 17th century. The origin of  these remains was long a matter of debate, and often explained as being remains of legendary  creatures. The mammoth was identified as an extinct species of elephant by Georges Cuvier in 1796.
The woolly mammoth was roughly the same size as modern African elephants. Males reached shoulder   heights between 2.7 and 3.4 m (9 and 11 ft) and weighed up to 6 tonnes (6.6 short tons). Females  averaged 2.6–2.9 metres (8.5–9.5 ft) in height and weighed up to 4 tonnes (4.4 short tons). A newborn calf weighed about 90 kilograms (200 lb). The woolly mammoth was well adapted to the cold environment during the last ice age. It was covered in fur, with an outer covering of long guard hairs and a shorter undercoat. The colour of the coat varied from dark to light. The ears and tail were short to minimise frostbite and heat loss. It had long, curved tusks and four molars, which were replaced six times during the lifetime of an individual. Its behaviour was similar to that of modern elephants, and it used its tusks and trunk for manipulating objects, fighting, and foraging. The diet of the woolly mammoth was mainly grass and sedges. Individuals could probably reach the age of 60. Its habitat was the mammoth steppe, which stretched across northern Eurasia and North America.
The woolly mammoth coexisted with early humans, who used its bones and tusks for making art, tools, and dwellings, and the species was also hunted for food.[1] It disappeared from its mainland range at the end of the Pleistocene 10,000 years ago, most likely through a combination of climate change, consequent disappearance of its habitat, and hunting by humans, though the significance of these factors is disputed. Isolated populations survived on Wrangel Island until 4,000 years ago, and on St. Paul Island until 6,400 years ago. After its extinction, humans continued using its ivory as a raw material, and this tradition continues today. It has been proposed the species could be recreated through cloning, but this method is as yet infeasible because of the degraded state of the remaining genetic material.
```

Comment: What errors/exceptions are you getting? Consider posting a stacktrace output.

Comment: Something looks wrong with your code; in particular `txtString.equals(word)`. Does the README.TXT file contain single words? If so, this *might* work. What's an example of the input file contents?

Comment: no they don't contain one words, it contains 50 words of choice from wikipedia, i know for a fact that it contains "the".

Comment: Here is the text file:   The woolly mammoth (Mammuthus primigenius) was a species of mammoth, the common name for the extinct elephant genus Mammuthus. The woolly mammoth was one of the last in a line of mammoth species, beginning with Mammuthus subplanifrons in the early Pliocene. M. primigenius diverged from the steppe mammoth, M. trogontherii, about 200,000 years ago in eastern Asia. Its closest extant relative is the Asian elephant.

Comment: @jdog1218 does your text file contain words without line separates ?add part of your textfile to question

Comment: @fast snail The fact that the lines are not line terminated is irrelevant. Then you get the next line it would get either the entire text contain on the file (a really long line) or the next sentence.  Either way, once you get a line, calling `next()` will return the next word on the line.  This is because this method returns the next `String` up to the first space it encounters. There is no need to split the string or use a second `Scanner` object to get the next word.

Comment: @hfontanez it's looks i was over thinking yes you are exactly right .but why i use 2 scanner is the  word which we want to find how much repeat is not "the" every time.so it asks "What word would you like to look up that may be repeated:" .to clarify things ii used 2 one for read file and one for take user input

Comment: My bad... I overlooked the need for a second `Scanner` object to get the next word the user may want to search for.  In that case, you do need a second object.  Point taken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working example .all you need to do is get the input from the user and store it in a String then read text file line by line ,if the line equals to userinput value then increase count variable 1 .in your code there is lot of redundant codes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class P6B {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\workingfox\\m2.txt"));
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int CountWord = 0;
        String word = null;

        System.out.println("\nThis program will read a text file with 50 random   words"
                + "\nWhat word would you like to look up that may be repeated: ");

         String text = input.next();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            word=reader.nextLine();
            if (text.equals(word)) {
                CountWord++;
            }
        }//to get words and return the value of how many times it was found
        if (CountWord != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nI have found your word " + CountWord + " times.");
        } else if (CountWord == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nNo word found in the text file.");
        }//end of if if error
    }
}
```

textfile content.

```
book
book
book
shel
groceries
```

output>>

```
This program will read a text file with 50 random   words
What word would you like to look up that may be repeated: 
book

I have found your word 3 times.
```

---

**updating ...**

if your textfile contain sequence of text in a single line you need to split lines by white spaces .

look this one... i added `split("\\s+");` which for  separate words in a line.if you want to match words ignoring cases then use `.equalsIgnoreCase` instead `.equals`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class P6Bxx {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\workingfox\\m2.txt"));
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int CountWord = 0;

        System.out.println("\nThis program will read a text file with 50 random   words"
                + "\nWhat word would you like to look up that may be repeated: ");

         String text = input.next();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String[] words = reader.nextLine().split("\\s+");
            for(String word : words){
                if (text.equals(word)) {
                    CountWord++;
                }
            }
        }//to get words and return the value of how many times it was found
        if (CountWord != 0) {
            System.out.println("\nI have found your word " + CountWord + " times.");
        } else if (CountWord == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nNo word found in the text file.");
        }//end of if if error
    }
}
```

textfile

```
The woolly mammoth (Mammuthus primigenius) was a species of mammoth, the common name for the     extinct elephant genus     
Mammuthus. The woolly mammoth was one of the last in a line of mammoth  species, beginning with Mammuthus subplanifrons in the    
early Pliocene. M. primigenius diverged from  the steppe mammoth, M. trogontherii, about 200,000 years ago in eastern Asia. Its 
closest extant relative is the Asian elephant.
```

output>>

```
This program will read a text file with 50 random   words
What word would you like to look up that may be repeated: 
mammoth

I have found your word 3 times.
```

Comment: it doesn't work, there is a "the" in the text file.  " This program will read a text file with 50 random   words
What word would you like to look up that may be repeated: 
the

No word found in the text file. "

Comment: @jdog1218 did you change C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\workingfox\\m2.txt to your text file path?

Comment: yay because that is where the file is in my program

Comment: so you are saying i half to make a text file line by line to read?

Comment: @jdog1218 what do you mean?i didn't get it .clarify

Comment: Every line downward in the text file is being read, not going from left to right.

Comment: @jdog1218 add part of your text file .then it's clear to viewers

Comment: I just added the text file content to the question, That is how it is in the text file.

Comment: ohh my god you need to split

Comment: Thanks that was probably the problem the whole time. Thanks

Comment: @jdog1218 i don't think your problem is fix.still remains?

Comment: What is it, so far its working for me. I have over 2,000 words in the text file. Splitting each one.

Comment: @jdog1218 anyway i updated the answer that will give you the exactly output

Comment: I just posted a more efficient solution.  There is no need for two Scanner objects to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code.

1. You only need one `Scanner` object and one loop.
2. Your inner `while` loop, should be replaced with an `if` statement where you increment your counter.
3. You may want to count matched words regardless of case sensitivity.  If that is the case, you need to call the `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()`.
4. Since you did not specified the type of Runtime problem you encountered, it is virtually impossible for me to figure out why you were getting that error.

I verified the program by opening your document in Notepad++ and verifying the count there.

```
public class P6B
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("README.TXT"));

        int CountWord = 0;
        String word = "the";
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
            String line = reader.next();
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(line))
            {
                CountWord++;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        if (CountWord != 0)
            System.out.println("I have found your word " + CountWord
                + " times.");
        else if (CountWord == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No word found in the text file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Program output:
    **I have found your word 28 times.**

**UPDATE:** count multiple words

```
public class P6B
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.print("Enter words to search separated by spaces: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in = input.nextLine();

        if (in.length() > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            String[] words = in.split("\\s");
            for (String word : words)
            {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("README.TXT"));
                while (reader.hasNext())
                {
                    String line = reader.next();
                    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(line))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("I have found the word \'" + word + "\' "
                        + count + ((count == 1) ? " time." : " times."));
                count = 0;
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

If you try the following:

```
Enter words to search separated by spaces: the woolly foo
```

You will obtain the following output:

```
I have found the word 'the' 28 times.
I have found the word 'woolly' 6 times.
I have found the word 'foo' 0 times.
```

Comment: I used the same text file. Using `next()` instead of `nextLine()` will get the next string up to the first white space it encounters. Therefore, it would get the next word.  You will then compare the next word to the searched word. If it matches, the counter variable is incremented. If not, you will continue with the loop. If the text file does not have line terminators, it will get the entire contents in one shot and not iterate. If it is broken down into lines, it will iterate through the lines until EOF.  The code works.  Feel free to try it.